# getting this error while running a ruby script

Tags: ruby

```
2: from apk-embed-payload.rb:9:in `<main>'
1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- colorize (LoadError)
```

Comment: _cannot load such file -- `colorize`_! What is `colorize`? Where is that file located relative to your script?

Comment: can you post the code that is giving this error?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have a `require 'colorize'` in your code, but the gem colorize is not installed. You can install the gem by running:

```
gem install colorize
```

I assume you have `gem` installed. Otherwise you need to install it as well.

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem.Thanks for helping and stay safe and stay indoors.